# Compare and print data from different text files to one in Shell

Tags: shell, awk, sort, join

How can I compare and print data from different text files to one in Shell.

I have captures `NAS` details of three different boxes using `SSH`, now I need to combine all the three text files to one file and **MOUNT NAME** should be in the first column and if the same **MOUNT** were present in he three boxes then it should print in same line and if the **MOUNT** is presented only in **BOX_B** and **BOX_C** then **MOUNT name** should present in first column and Column for **Box_A** should be kept blank

Lets take two examples **df_BoxA.txt** and **df_BoxB.txt** and **df_BoxC.txt**

Example:

```
$cat df_BoxA.txt  
/logs/boxA      2G     1.2G     7.7G    62%             NAS:/logs/boxA
/data/boxA      2G     1.8G     2.0G    91%             NAS:/data/boxA 
/apps/boxA      2G     1.4G     5.7G    72%             NAS:/apps/boxA 
/data/java      1G     67M      9.3G    7%              NAS:/data/java
/home/admin     10G    4.6G     54G     46%             NAS:/home/admin
/admin/arch     10G    8.3G     19G     83%             NAS:/admin/arch
/apps/dist      10G    8.3G     19G     83%             NAS:/apps/dist



$cat df_BoxB.txt  
/logs/boxA      2G     1.2G     7.7G    62%             NAS:/logs/boxB
/data/boxA      2G     1.8G     2.0G    91%             NAS:/data/boxB 
/apps/boxA      2G     1.4G     5.7G    72%             NAS:/apps/boxB 
/home/user      40G    29.3G    107G    74%             NAS:/home/user1 
/data/java      1G     67M      9.3G    7%              NAS:/data/java
/home/admin     10G    4.6G     54G     46%             NAS:/home/admin
/apps/dist      10G    8.3G     19G     83%             NAS:/apps/dist


$cat df_BoxC.txt  
/logs/boxA      2G     1.2G     7.7G    62%             NAS:/logs/boxC
/data/boxA      2G     1.8G     2.0G    91%             NAS:/data/boxC 
/apps/boxA      2G     1.4G     5.7G    72%             NAS:/apps/boxC 
/home/user1     40G    29.3G    107G    74%             NAS:/home/user1 
/home/admin     10G    4.6G     54G     46%             NAS:/home/admin
/admin/arch     10G    8.3G     19G     83%             NAS:/admin/arch
/apps/dist      10G    8.3G     19G     83%             NAS:/apps/dist
```

After combining all the three files the result should be like

```
$cat result.txt 
/logs/boxA   2G     1.2G     7.7G    62% NAS:/logs/boxA 2G  1.2G  7.7G  62% NAS:/logs/boxB  2G   1.2G  7.7G  62% NAS:/logs/boxC
/data/boxA   2G     1.8G     2.0G    91% NAS:/data/boxA 2G  1.8G  2.0G  91% NAS:/data/boxB  2G   1.8G  2.0G  91% NAS:/data/boxC
/apps/boxA   2G     1.4G     5.7G    72% NAS:/apps/boxA 2G  1.4G  5.7G  72% NAS:/apps/boxB  2G   1.4G  5.7G  72% NAS:/apps/boxC 
/data/java   1G     67M     9.3G    7%   NAS:/data/java 1G  67M   9.3G  7%  NAS:/data/java
/home/admin  10G    4.6G     54G     46% NAS:/home/admin10G 4.6G  54G   46% NAS:/home/admin 10G  4.6G  54G   46% NAS:/home/admin
/admin/arch  10G    8.3G     19G     83% NAS:/admin/arch                                    10G  8.3G  19G   83% NAS:/admin/arch
/apps/dist   10G    8.3G     19G     83% NAS:/apps/dist 10G 8.3G  19G   83% NAS:/apps/dist  10G  8.3G  19G   83% NAS:/apps/dist
/home/user                                              40G 29.3G 107G  74% NAS:/home/user1 
/home/user1                                                                                 40G  29.3G 107G  74% NAS:/home/user1
```

I have tried of using `pr` command which is combining of the files which not the required result.

Also tried of using `sdiff` but unable to get result.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can use `paste -d'' file1 file2 file3`. That's what paste does

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do requires a little programming:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Program to join files of TAB separated data based on first key
# --J. Ziobro--: 11/2014
use strict;
my $f;
my %allLines;
my $maxColumns = 0;
my $fileNum    = 0;
my %keys;
foreach $f (@ARGV) {
    die "Could not open $f" unless open( F, $f );
    while (<F>) {
        chop;
        my ( $key, @line ) = split /\t/;    # assume tab separate all cols
        $maxColumns = ( $maxColumns > @line ) ? $maxColumns : @line;

        # allLines is indexed by KEY <tab> FileNumber
        $keys{$key} = 1;
        $allLines{ $key . "\t" . $fileNum } = join( "\t", @line );
    }
    $fileNum++;
}
foreach ( keys %keys ) {
    print $_;
    for ( $f = 0 ; $f < $fileNum ; $f++ ) {
        if ( exists $allLines{ $_ . "\t" . $f } ) {
            print "\t", $allLines{ $_ . "\t" . $f };
        }
        else {
            print "     " x $maxColumns;
        }
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Ciao,//Z\

Answer (score -1):

I'm *pretty sure* you're looking for `join`. Unfortunately, I'm not very good with it. I know there's a way to make it fill the fields the way you want as well, but so far I can only get the unpaired lines to print at the head of the line. `join` only joins two files at a time, and so the unpaired lines don't show where you want - at least, I *think* they don't. Your question is a little unclear to me - my apologies.

Anyway, to use `join` you must first `sort` the input on the *join field* - which is by default the first and what I went with here:

```
for f in file[123]
do sort <<IN >"$f"
$(cat "$f")
IN
done
```

Next, as I said, `join` only joins two files at a time so I `join`ed the first two and piped that output to another `join` for the third:

```
join -a1 -a2 file[12] | 
join -a1 -a2 - file3  | 
column -t | sort -hk2,2
```

I also piped it through `column` and `sort` again for formatting. The results follow:

```
/data/java   1G   67M    9.3G  7%   NAS:/data/java   1G   67M   9.3G  7%   NAS:/data/java
/apps/boxA   2G   1.4G   5.7G  72%  NAS:/apps/boxA   2G   1.4G  5.7G  72%  NAS:/apps/boxB   2G   1.4G  5.7G  72%  NAS:/apps/boxC
/data/boxA   2G   1.8G   2.0G  91%  NAS:/data/boxA   2G   1.8G  2.0G  91%  NAS:/data/boxB   2G   1.8G  2.0G  91%  NAS:/data/boxC
/logs/boxA   2G   1.2G   7.7G  62%  NAS:/logs/boxA   2G   1.2G  7.7G  62%  NAS:/logs/boxB   2G   1.2G  7.7G  62%  NAS:/logs/boxC
/admin/arch  10G  8.3G   19G   83%  NAS:/admin/arch  10G  8.3G  19G   83%  NAS:/admin/arch
/apps/dist   10G  8.3G   19G   83%  NAS:/apps/dist   10G  8.3G  19G   83%  NAS:/apps/dist   10G  8.3G  19G   83%  NAS:/apps/dist
/home/admin  10G  4.6G   54G   46%  NAS:/home/admin  10G  4.6G  54G   46%  NAS:/home/admin  10G  4.6G  54G   46%  NAS:/home/admin
/home/user1  40G  29.3G  107G  74%  NAS:/home/user1
/home/user   40G  29.3G  107G  74%  NAS:/home/user1
```