# Remove everything that is not a 4 character number

Tags: text-processing

I need to remove everything that is not a 4 character number such as `9838`, `6738`, `1337` or `1889`.

I though that this command would work:

```
sed 's/....[^0-9]//g'
```

`.` Means any character in regex, and `[^0-9]` removes none numbers.

Here is an example input:

```
9228 Hello 8473 World War 1 1914-1918 Hello 8391 World War 2 1939-1945
```

Would be:

```
9228 8473 1914 1918 8391 1939 1945
```

Comment: What about in `foo1234bar` or `0x1234ff` or `1.1234`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It would output `1234 1234 1234`.

Comment: What about an 8 digit number or 9 digit, how would you decide which to drop, or would you print all combinations in it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can answer with `grep` command:

#### Input file:

```
9228 Hello 8473 World War 1 1914-1918 Hello 8391 World War 2 1939-1945
```

#### Command:

```
grep -Eo '\<[0-9]{4}\>' file |tr '\n' ' '
```

Return any number with length=4.

`-E` switches to extended regex
`-o` print only the matching part

#### Output:

```
9228 8473 1914 1918 8391 1939 1945
```

---

#### Update answer:

#### Input file:

```
9228 Hello 8473 World War 1 1914-1918 Hello 8391 World War 2 1939-1945

foo1234bar
a1111
12345
0x2222ff
1.3333
2.54321
```

#### Command

```
grep -oP '(?<![0-9])[0-9]{4}(?![0-9])' file | tr '\n' ' '
```

grep with negative lookbehind/lookahead:

`(?<![0-9])[0-9]{4}` (negative lookbehind): matches numbers to length=4 that is not preceded by a number`[0-9]`.
`[0-9]{4}(?![0-9])` (negative lookahead): match numbers to length=4 not followed by a number.

#### Output:

```
9228 8473 1914 1918 8391 1939 1945 1234 1111 2222 3333
```

Comment: Not "*max* length". It'll capture numbers with **exactly** 4 digits.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith Uh yes my mistake ;) thank you

Comment: @KasiyA  you can add `.. file | tr '\n' ' '`  to put the numbers in the same line.

Comment: This seems to work but will also give you strings with more than 4 digits.  You can fix that by changing the regex pattern to: `\<[0-9]{4}\>'.  The angular brackets delimit words.

Comment: @unxnut No, it won't. `{4}` will limit to **exactly** 4 digits, and this is what the author has written. Try it ;)

Comment: **unxnut** **val0x00ff** **JohnWhSmith** thank you fixed

Comment: @JohnWHSmith: I had tried it and it gave me the first four digits of a five digit string without the angular brackets.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `perl`.

```
perl -nle'print join " ", /(?<![0-9])[0-9]{4}(?![0-9])/g'
```

This also works for multi-line input, so if you have:

```
9228 Hello 8473 World War 1 1914-1918
Hello 8391 World War 2 1939-1945
```

You'll get the following returned:

```
9228 8473 1914 1918
8391 1939 1945
```

(Add `-0777` if you want the numbers on the same line.)

Comment: Might be faster: `perl -nle'print join " ", grep { length($_) == 4) } /[0-9]+/g'`

Answer (score 4):

POSIXly:

```
< file tr -cs 0-9 '[\n*]' | grep -xE '.{4}' | paste  -sd ' ' -
```

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -Tnle 'BEGIN {$, = " "} print $_ =~ /\b\d{4}\b/g' file
9228 8473 1914 1918 8391 1939 1945
```

Comment: That matches 1234 in 12345 though (and not 2345).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Good point. It will be better now.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Add `-T` for filename beginning or ending with `|` after reading your editing. Can you give some reference for this? I only read `perldoc -f open`, and it has a little information.

Comment: @cuonglm Prints empty line if not match with pattern. example for `12345`

Comment: @KasiyA: I think it fit in with OP's requirement. All things which is not 4 digit long will be removed. So when not matches, all things was removed.

Comment: See `perldoc perlop` about `<>`. for `file`, it's OK, for `*`, it's not as you've got an issue if there's a file called `rm -rf "$HOME"|` for instance in your current directory, as I've just found out. `-T` avoids the damage, but it not the solution. I'm starting to review all my perl answers to see where that applies and give warnings there. Serious blow to my confidence in `perl`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: It's not problem when you use `open` with three-arguments form. It seems that `-n` and `-p` don't use that form.

Comment: No, they use `<>`. See `perl -e '<>' 'uname>&2|'` and `perl -ne '' 'uname>&2|'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: `<>` is null filehandle, and null filehandle uses the two arguments form of `open`. See: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators

Comment: Yes, which is where the problem is. `perl -ne '' *` in a directory writeable by others is a security vulnerability. `perl -Tne '' *` is not as bad (still of DoS). `perl -MARGV::readonly -ne '' *` would be a fix, but ARGV::readonly (a 10-liner module) is not usually installed by default...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: We can do the same things like that module in `BEGIN` block.

Comment: @cuonglm, yes. Less than ideal though. I'll create a Q&A here for awareness. As it took me almost 20 years of using `perl` to stumble into it.

Answer (score 1):

With a single `s///` you can do this in a POSIX `sed` - but there are a lot of backslashes:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\{5,\}\)*[^0-9]*\([0-9]\{4\}\)*.\{0,1\}/ \2/g
' <<\IN
92828 Hello 8473 World War 1 1914-1918 Hello 8391 World War 2 1939-1945
IN
```

#### OUTPUT

```
8473  1914 1918 8391  1939 1945
```

It `g`lobally gobbles all of the sequences with 5 or more digits first - then any `^`not digits - *then* your match, and last 0 or 1 of any other character. In that entire statement only 1 expression is saved - your match - and so, that is what remains - besides any intervening blanks.

But with a little translation things get easier:

```
sed 'y/ /./;s/[0-9]\{4,\}/ & /g;s/\( [^ ]\{4\} \)*[^ ]*/\1/g
' <<\IN
92828 Hello 8473 World War 1 1914-1918 Hello 8391 World War 2 1939-1945
IN
```

#### OUTPUT

```
  8473  1914  1918  8391  1939  1945
```

`sed` first transliterates all spaces to dots. It next wraps any sequence of 4 or more digits in spaces. And last it removes all not-space characters save any sequence of four surrounded by spaces.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - thank you for the edit. I didn't even consider that context at all. Maybe you might have a look at [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169934/52934)? I made an attempt - but I'm kind of hopeless w/ `join` and I think probably you could a better answer for the guy.

Answer (score 0):

with `gawk`

```
echo '9228 Hello 8473 World War 1 1914-1918 Hello 8391 World War 2 1939-1945' |
awk --re-interval -v RS='\\y[[:digit:]]{4}\\y' '{printf "%s ", RT}END{print ""}'
9228 8473 1914 1918 8391 1939 1945
```

Comment: That matches 1234 in 12345 though (and not 2345).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, hmm.. good point. I've attempted to address that with word boundaries now

Answer (score 0):

**Python**

In python i would do like the below,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import sys
file = sys.argv[1]
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print ' '.join(re.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)', line))
```

Save the above script as `script.py` and then run it by applying the below command on the terminal.

```
python script.py file
```

*Example:*

```
$ cat file
9228 Hello 8473 World War 1 1914-1918 Hello 8391 World War 2 1939-1945
foo1234bar 0x1234ff 1.1234
$ python f.py file
9228 8473 1914 1918 8391 1939 1945
1234 1234 1234
```

**Perl**

Through perl's `s///` command. That is search and replace command.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)(*SKIP)(*F)|.+?(?=\d{4}|$)/ /g;s/^ +| +$//g' file
```

*Example:*

```
$ cat file
9228 Hello 8473 World War 1 1914-1918 Hello
foo1234bar 0x1234ff 1.1234
$ perl -pe 's/(?<!\d)\d{4}(?!\d)(*SKIP)(*F)|.+?(?=\d{4}|$)/ /g;s/^ +| +$//g' file
9228 8473 1914 1918
1234 1234 1234
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26272200/3297613) to know more about the PCRE verb `(*SKIP)(*F)`.

Comment: positive and negative lookahead assertions are overkill when word boundaries `\b` would suffice

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you need another version of answer based on `sed`.

```
$ sed -re 's#(\b[0-9]{4}\b)*([^0-9]|\b[0-9]\b)*#\1 #g' file.txt
9228 8473 1914 1918 8391 1939 1945
```